# Can a two column layout shrink to 1 column if no content present in first column?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have posted my workaround to illustrate my problem at the end of this post.

I have two columns, the left one may or may not contain an image thumbnail and the right one that always contains text.

The image containers width is set at a % and the image itself fills 100% of its parents width with an proportional height.

The img then has the equivalant of background-size:cover applied to center, crop and fill its parent container.

Is there any way with css to have the text column fill 100% of the width of the blog-container if there is no thumbnail image added?

My current solution which involves using :empty to display:none the img tags parent container if there is no content in it but I need a solution where I can specify a width of image-container instead, and have it shrink to 0 if no image present.

Hopefully this isnt too convoluted, any clarification please ask. Support back to IE10 required. I was hoping flexbox could help?

```
<div class="blog-container">

     <div class="featured-image-container">
          <div class="featured-image-blog"><?php the_post_thumbnail('this is the img'); ?</div>
     </div>

      <div class="blog-entry-content-container">
          <div class="blog-excerpt-container">
              <?php the_excerpt;?>
          </div>
      </div>

 </div>

//SCSS
@mixin maintain-ratio($ratio: 1 1) {
@if length($ratio) < 2 or length($ratio)>2 {
    @warn "$ratio must be a list with two values.";
}
$width: 100%;
$height: percentage(nth($ratio, 2) / nth($ratio, 1));
width: $width;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: $height;
}

//CSS

.blog-container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}

.ourblog .featured-image-blog {
width:32%!important;/*I WANT TO MOVE THIS TO A PARENT CONTAINER (.image-container)*/
@include maintain-ratio(3 1);
margin: 10px 25px 20px 0!important;
font-size: 0!important;
position:relative!important;
overflow:hidden;   }

.ourblog .featured-image-blog img {
position: absolute;
/* Position the image in the middle of its container. */
top: -9999px;
right: -9999px;
bottom: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
margin: auto;
/* The following values determine the exact image behaviour. */
/* You can simulate background-size: cover/contain/etc.
 by changing between min/max/standard width/height values.
 These values simulate background-size: cover
 */
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

/*hide empty featured image container. !!!ensure no whitespace between tags in html!!! */
.ourblog .featured-image-blog:empty {
display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex row then set then use the flex shorthand on the columns to make them flex to the available space. Basic example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpYzaV

```
.blog-container {
width: 100%;
display: flex; // is flex row by default
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.featured-image-container {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.blog-entry-content-container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

Use has post thumbnail to render the container if it has an image set.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <!-- show the image container -->
    <div class="featured-image-container">  
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <!-- show nothing -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: In your example if I remove the image tags the 'content' column would the need to stretch to be 100%.

Comment: You can use the has post thumbnail function to conditionally render the featured-image-container. If the featured-image-container is not there the content col will be 100%; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/

Comment: any chance you could give me an example of the conditional statement? I have this but its not working:   

<div class="featured-image-container"><div class="featured-image-blog"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail();}
            }else{?>
                <style type="text/css">.featured-image-container{
                display:none;}</style><?php 
                 }?>
                 
          
          </div></div>

Comment: Added PHP to the answer above.